# How do you unlock the Sprinter Kart and Mii Outfit B in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

In Mario Kart Wii I have unlocked everything except the Sprinter Medium Kart and the Mii Outfit B.

How do I unlock these?

Answer (score 3):

Unlocking the Sprinter requires you to unlock 24 Expert Staff Ghosts.
Unlocking the Mii Outfit B requires you to unlock all 32 Expert Staff Ghosts (one for each track).

You unlock the Expert Staff Ghosts by beating a specific time on Time Trials for each track, while racing against the Normal Staff Ghost.

There are many [online](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii#Expert_Staff_Ghosts) [links](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/942008-mario-kart-wii/45308948) that show the times you need - generally if you can beat the Normal Staff Ghost by 3 or 4 seconds, you will unlock the Expert Staff Ghost.

Comment: Thank you very much! But what if theydo that zero second cheat? Anyway, thanks so much i am gonna start practicing right now!:)

Comment: The Staff Ghosts are not real people, though they may possibly be recordings of real people racing.  They do not cheat, but run the course exactly the same every time.  All you have to do is beat a specific time to unlock the Expert Staff Ghost - you don't even have to beat that ghost (though you are welcome to try).

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that my best record for SNES ghost valley two is twenty one sexonds! But my ghost has a different record of mine. Can i change it? You are really helpful. :)

Comment: @zoe You've already asked a question about this.  That's the correct way to go about it.  Don't ask different questions in the comments.