# How do i unlock mii outfit B on mario kart wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I really want to find out, please answer! I have mii outfit a, too. But i want to earn mii outfit b. By the way, is mii outfit C real or fake or perhaps a mistake in the game?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Zoe!  There is no Outfit C and I have answered your first question with regards to unlocking Outfit B.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please don't the same question more than once. I vote to close this question and use your other one at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128478/how-do-you-unlock-the-sprinter-kart-and-mii-outfit-b-in-mario-kart-wii

Comment: Sorry, sometimes its slow and i press the submit question button more than once. Thanks for welcoming me. :)