# How can I change the time trial ghost?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I'm currently doing time trials, and I just learned that my best lap on Ghost Valley 2 is 21 seconds. My ghost, however, uses a different record. How can I change it to use my best time?

Answer (score 1):

During Time Trials, two numbers are tracked:

1. Your fastest lap time (in this case 21 seconds).
2. The time it took for you to complete three laps.

It is this second number that is used for unlocking Expert Staff Ghosts (as per [your previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128478/how-do-you-unlock-the-sprinter-kart-and-mii-outfit-b-in-mario-kart-wii)).  For Ghost Valley 2, you are trying to beat 1:04 in three laps, so three 21 second laps would work (though your first lap is always a bit slower, due to the fact that you must accelerate from a stop).

You cannot change the times.  You can practice and try again.

Comment: But the fastest time i completed a lap was 15 seconds, not twenty one. I dont even remember doing twenty one, but, thank you for the advice

Comment: I always thought it meant 21 seconds for all three laps. Whoever you are, ur smart and thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

21 seconds is your best lap time, not best overall time. So, unless that 21 second lap time was also part of your best complete run of the course, you will likely not be able to select it to race against.

That said, changing which ghost you race against is fairly easy.

1. Go the menu used to select a time trial track.
2. Select the track, but do not start the race.
   You should be on a menu showing the  ghost you are going to race.
3. Use the joystick (left and right) to select a different ghost.

iirc only ghost with the best time for each mii/player is kept.